# Android studio gradle complie time error

Tags: android, gradle, compiler-errors

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzni;

Comment: Please post your dependency chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable multidex add these lines in app level build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wowio.ebookreader"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled true

}


dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}
```

and add this dependency

```
 dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If **Build** > **Clean Project** doesn't work, you are probably adding Google Play Service from multiple places, or probably one of your dependencies is.

You can try adding the following in your `build.gradle` within `android {}`:

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'com/google/android/gms/*'
    pickFirst 'com/google/android/gms/**/*'
}
```

It will pick the first classes that it comes accross.